# My fiberglass insert shower tub has vertical play in the middle, what can I do?

Tags: bathroom-fixtures

My fiberglass insert shower tub has vertical play in the middle. Meaning when I go to stand in the shower, the bottom of the tub sags from lack of support from beneath the tub. I don't have any access from behind on the side's or beneath the tub. Would it be crazy to drill a few small holes in the bottom of the tub and use high expansion spray foam to fill the void beneath and then patch the small drilled holes?

Comment: How big is the play?  Drilling a hole is a bad idea.  Sooner or later water is going to leak out and cause damage.  Does it stay flexible, or does the bottom meet the floor (with your weight)?

Comment: @RohitGupta I'm wondering if the OP means the bottom of the tub *apron.*

Comment: See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/11790/18078 for some options. Rather than drilling through part of the tub, coming in from the wall behind, or an end, or even up through the floor is usually better. drywall is easier to patch than a fiberglass tub. If using foam (which is certainly the easiest retrofit support) you may want to partically fill the ub with water.

Comment: When stepping into the tub you can feel the flex under your weight. It doesn't feel like the bottom is meeting the floor. We have no access to the underside of the tub from any direction. From what I imagine there is subfloor beneath so access that way would be very difficult to attack from below